# How to read/write type values from "raw" memory in C?

Tags: c, memory, casting, memory-access

How do I make something like this work?

```
void *memory = malloc(1000);  //allocate a pool of memory
*(memory+10) = 1;  //set an integer value at byte 10
int i = *(memory+10);  //read an integer value from the 10th byte
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Easy example: treat the memory as an array of unsigned char

```
void *memory = malloc(1000);  //allocate a pool of memory
uint8_t *ptr = memory+10;  
*ptr = 1 //set an integer value at byte 10
uint8_t i = *ptr;  //read an integer value from the 10th byte
```

You can use integers too, but then you must pay attention about the amount of bytes you are setting at once.

Comment: Is it possible to do this with casting the void pointer instead of creating an "intermediate" typed pointer?

Comment: of course, I use an intermediate representation for the sake of clarity

Answer (score 5):

The rules are simple:

- every pointer type (except function pointers) can be cast to and from void*, without loss.
- you cannot perform pointer arithmetic on void* pointers, and cannot dereference them
- sizeof(char) equals 1, by definition; so incrementing a char pointer means "adding 1" to the "raw" pointer value

From this you can conclude that if you want to perform "raw" pointer arithmetic you have to cast to and from char*.

Answer (score 3):

So, by "work" I assume you mean "how do I dereference/perform pointer arithmetic on a `void*`"?  You can't; you have to cast it, typically to a `char*` if you're just concerned with reading chunks of memory.  Of course, if that's the case, simply declare it as a `char*` to begin with.

Comment: @ddriver: That changes nothing.  You have to cast the pointer. How would you expect a dereference and/or arithmetic to act when the type is unknown?  It makes no sense.  You will need to pass additional information to know what the underlying type is.