# how to read raw memory in c

Tags: c, memory, memory-management

I want to define a buffer of any size which gets some space allocated in the memory. I want to read existing data inside the memory allocated to that buffer.

I have tried following code but all I am just seeing some special characters every time.

If I take dump of my memory via DumpIt tool and then open it via HEX Editor, I can see normal characters (like digits and abc etc).

I used following code which uses two techniques [first mentioned here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11490984/how-to-read-write-type-values-from-raw-memory-in-c) and second uses just simple array and go through each character one by one.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <process.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <stdint.h> 

int main()
{
    int x = 4;
    char arr[400];
    char * src;
    src = arr;

    uint8_t *memory = (uint8_t *) malloc(1000);  
    while(*memory != NULL) {
        printf("Character %c\n", *(memory++));
        memory++;
    }

    while(src != NULL) {
        printf("%c ", *src);
        x++;
        if(x == 1000)
            break;
    }
    printf("And the data stored in memory is %s\n", arr);

    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why are you expecting to see anything meaningful? Also remember you're most likely running on a system with virtual memory; you won't read any other process's memory like that.

Comment: you seem to be confused, you can't read random "memory," with virtual memory there's no such thing as reading "raw" memory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you run malloc, you're just going to get random stuff in that memory segment. Some of it won't be able to be encoded into anything readable with ASCII. You could try printing the hex values of what's in memory with "%X" instead of "%c".

Though I have no idea why you would want to do such a thing.

Comment: Curiosity is the only thing I can think of.

Comment: Okei. I want to see this 'random stuff' what exactly it is. If I cant see human readable characters by this way, why I am able to find human-readable-characters in the memory when I use DumpIt tool to take dump of memory and HexEditor to open this dump file. Thanks

Comment: Most hex editors will replace all unreadable characters with something like a period, you could be seeing that. For instance, you might see something like "71 bf 8f b1 65 77 4c 55    q...ewLU". The "."s are just the hex editor replacing unreadable characters with a symbol so it's easier for you to read.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't tell us on what type of system you are running your code (`conion.h` lets me fear the worst), but on any decent system you will never get "random" data like that. All pages that you *get* from the system will be cleared out for security reasons, since otherwise any process could read whatever another process has left over, passwords, love letters, ...

You may eventually see pseudo random stuff that your own process has left over on the heap or on the stack when initializing, calling another function, whatever. But that is all "randomness" that you can expect from that.

*Nitpicks:*

- Don't cast the return of `malloc`
- your line

-

```
printf("And the data stored in memory is %s\n", arr);
```

makes not much sense. This print statement stops printing at the first null character that is encountered.

Comment: That makes sense. Just one more follow up question: When does an OS wipes out memory? When a old program exits or when a new program tries to access that page? And is there any Windows link about memory wiping for processes? I can only find for hard-drives, Usb etc. Thanks